# Place a node over wires without it auto-connecting

Tags: interface, node-editor

Sometimes I'll be trying to place a node and there is a wire beneath it in the way. By "in the way" I mean that if I place the node where I want to it will automatically connect in a way I don't intend it to. Is there a some way to simply drop the node in place without connecting the wires?

I've tried all the modifier keys but nothing worked.

Also, I don't want want to disable auto-connect *entirely*, but I would like to be able to *momentarily* disable it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The auto-connecting feature is currently inseparable from the Node Editor's translate operations, but you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to **Detach** the node after moving it, effectively "undoing" the auto-connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Alt + D** to detach the node, but in recent versions, it enters move mode automatically.

If you wish to prevent that from happening, follow these steps:

Under preferences -> keymap, type in detach in the search bar. You'll come across a few in the **node editor** region.

Expand the one with **Alt + D** assigned to it to expose the command code right below it.

Replace `node.move_detach_links` with `node.links_detach`. That will stop it from re-entering move mode.

Answer (score -1):

If you right click to place the node instead of using left click, it will place the node without auto connecting. Enjoy

Comment: When I try right-clicking, it moves the node to it's original location (canceling movement) instead of placing it without connecting. 

Comment: I think they mean *after* typing ALT D which sets the node in the correct position but still it requires another keyboard entry... Agree this shouldn't be an answer on its own